# undefined reference to `_addcarry_u64'

Tags: c, intel, intrinsics

I have code like this:

```
uint8_t carry;

carry = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    carry = _addcarry_u64 (carry, *(buf1 + i),
            *(buf2 + i), buf1 + i);
```

And the following error:

```
undefined reference to `_addcarry_u64'
```

I compile with flags:

```
CCFLAGS = -Wall -g -msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4 -mavx -mavx2 -fopenmp
```

I also include:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
```

The same kind of problem I have while trying to use `bittest` function from intrinsics.

I use x86_64 ubuntu 14.04 and gcc compiler.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229371/addcarry-u64-and-addcarryx-u64-with-msvc-and-icc

Comment: didn't find the answer to my question there

Comment: you'll need GCC 5.1 or above...

Comment: Already tried using gcc 5.3.0, still no effect

Comment: then you're missing `#include <x86intrin.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_addcarry_u64` was added in GCC 5.1. You also need the intrinsics include:

```
 #include <x86intrin.h>
```

Then your example will compile, like you can see [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu99+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dbroadwell',source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cx86intrin.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+adc(uint64_t+*buf1,+uint64_t+*buf2)%7B%0A++uint8_t+carry+%3D+0%3B%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+100%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++++carry+%3D+_addcarryx_u64+(carry,+*(buf1+%2B+i),%0A++++++++++++*(buf2+%2B+i),+buf1+%2B+i)%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

---

For the related [`_addcarryx_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=addcarr&expand=138,140) intrinsic to actually compile to [ADCX](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADCX.html)/ADOX, you also need `-madx` to enable code-gen using the ADX instruction-set extension.  `-march=native` will include this on hosts that support it (see `/proc/cpuinfo`), as well as enabling `-mtune=native`.

You also need a newer version of gcc (which doesn't exist yet).  [gcc curently (2016) just compiles it to correct code using the normal `adc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39320944/224132).

Comment: @jww: fixed your edit: _addcarryx_u64 and _addcarry_u64 aren't the same thing.  (Although my guess is that they will both compile to ADCX/ADOX with `-madx` in some future gcc and clang version.  If you tell the compiler the target supports it, why would it *not* use it if it can make more efficient code?)