# Get the number of times uint64 has exceeded its limit while multiplying uint64 * uint64

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to get the amount of overflows done while multiplying **uint64_t** on **uint64_t**. This can be calculated by the formula below, but I don't have access to 128 bit integers.

The example pseudocode with the usage of **uint128_t**:

```
uint64_t x = ...
uint64_t y = ...
uint128_t result = (uint128_t)x * (uint128_t)y / ((uint128_t)1 << 64);
```

Also it can be implemented by splitting `uint128_t` to `[uint64_t, uint64_t]` and performing the calculations from example. I consider not using it as I afraid it is pretty slow.

Comment: Do you want to calculate `result` or "the amount of overflows done"?

Comment: what is "amount of overflows" ? the diff between the real result (without overflow / on at least 128bits) and the result with an overflow ? but which overflow ? the effect of an overflow is not specified by C

Comment: "amount of overflows" is the amount of times when uint64 exceeded over 2**64 and was reset to 0.

Comment: So the "amount of overflows" is either 0 or 1, right?

Comment: BTW `(UINT64_MAX + 1)` can be 0 because of the overflow on `uint64_t`, very probably `UINT64_MAX` is defined as a `uint64_t`, not good to divide by 0 ...

Comment: @anatolyg, "amount of overflows" can be up to (2^64 * 2^64)/2^64 = 2^64.

Comment: `uint64_t * uint64_t` produces a `uint64_t` not a `uint128_t` and as I said `(UINT64_MAX + 1)` is very probably 0 (even not sure), what result do you expect ?

Comment: by pity can you use variables somewhere in `uint128_t(uint64_t) * uint128_t(uint64_t)`  
 to make the code valid in C ^^

Comment: It is a pseudocode, I used these statements to make the example look clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @AlexanderSadovskyi `uint128_t(uint64_t) * uint128_t(uint64_t)` is not clear at all  ... to add a line declaring the two variables just need 1 line allowing to use them in your expression

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You just want to calculate the mathematical formula, without regard to what its significance is. It just happens to be the number of overflows which occur when applying some hypothetical 64x64 multiplication algorithm. Is this correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?"
Exactly.

Comment: I updated the code to be more C-like. I have never used `uint128_t` but I think this code is now mostly runnable by a compiler which has it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what machine or compiler features you do or don't have, seeing as you've already rejected a few?  If you really have nothing beyond ISO C then I don't think there's anything you can do other than doing the multiple-precision multiplication in 64-bit chunks; is that what you refer to with the last paragraph?  By my count it needs 4 multiplies and a few cheap shifts and adds; doesn't sound that horrible to me.

Comment: Don't familiar with multi-precision multiplication. "4 multiplies and a few cheap shifts and adds" - If it is, then how can I implement it? If it wouldn't be hard for you, could you please write code and post it as an answer?

Comment: I see anatolyg beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a "clean" (portable) solution, do multiplication of 32-bit halves.

Using mathematical notation:

```
x = x1 * 2^32 + x0
y = y1 * 2^32 + y0
```

then

```
x * y = x1 * y1 * 2^64 + (x1 * y0 + x0 * y1) * 2^32 + x0 * y0
```

Here, all x<sub>n</sub> * y<sub>n</sub> fit into 64 bits. The only tricky part is doing the additions without losing the overflow (carry) bits.

For that, you can use the following code, which checks whether an overflow occurs when adding two 64-bit numbers.

```
bool overflow(uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    return x + y < x;
}
```

Here is code which calculates the high 64-bit part of 128-bit multiplication:

```
uint64_t doit(uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    // Calculate 64-bit parts of the 128-bit result
    uint64_t x1 = x >> 32;
    uint64_t x0 = x << 32 >> 32;
    uint64_t y1 = y >> 32;
    uint64_t y0 = y << 32 >> 32;
    uint64_t part0 = x0 * y0;
    uint64_t part1 = x1 * y0;
    uint64_t part2 = x0 * y1;
    uint64_t part3 = x1 * y1;
    /// Use part3
    uint64_t result = part3;
    // Use the 32-bit high halves of part1 and part2
    result += part1 >> 32;
    result += part2 >> 32;
    // Throw away their high half; multiply by 2^32
    part1 <<= 32;
    part2 <<= 32;
    // Calculate the 65-bit sum of parts 1 and 2
    bool carry = overflow(part1, part2)
    result += carry;
    uint64_t temp = part1 + part2;
    // Use part0
    carry = overflow(temp, part0)
    result += carry;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was writing my own function similar to this, so here is a godbolt link with both, plus the `__int128` for verification: https://godbolt.org/z/j5H-qm  Unfortunately I think yours has a bug somewhere as it gives different answers.

Comment: Fixed; the code works now. Interesting perspective on that godbolt link! I wonder if it's possible to convince the compiler to produce code with a single multiplication instruction.

Comment: Mine had some bugs too ;-)  Here is a new link with everything fixed, I hope. https://godbolt.org/z/SxvoaW

Comment: Look OK, yet the steps to find `overflow()` could be done with 32-bit args

Comment: Perhaps after `result += part2 >> 32;`, simplify to `return result + ((part2 & UINT32_MAX) +  (part1 & UINT32_MAX) + (part0 >> 32)) >> 32;`?

Comment: It's a matter of personal taste. If you think the code is obvious, you can do it one-liner-style. Considering the context of this code, I cannot assume the code is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Intel 64-bit architecture has an instruction which multiplies two 64-bit numbers, with 128-bit result. To access it, you have the [`_mulx_u64` intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549250/509868).

After the multiplication, you just get the high 64-bit part as your `result`, and throw away the low part.

Comment: Looks like the best answer here, but unfortunately I don't target the Intel CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying there is no portable way of doing this, because there is no `int128_t` in the C++20 standard or below.

With that in mind, in Windows you can achieve this by using the [`MultiplyExtract128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-multiplyextract128) function. Use 64 as the shift parameter to divide by `2^64`.

Comment: Sure it can be done portably - you emulate the 128-bit multiply with 64-bit operations, e.g. via grade-school long multiplication.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but the question was about C, not C++.

Comment: Noted, not interested in a software solution, but if that's how you write your programs then more power to you.

Comment: @AlexanderSadovskyi that function is a C function, what do you mean?

Comment: If OP has no access to anything machine-specific intrinsics or anything else beyond portable C, which seems to be the case, then I don't see what else can be done.

Comment: Sorry, It is actually a C function. Unfortunately I don't target Windows or any specific hardware/OS.