# How to specify target CPU/architecture Haswell for MSVC Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, compiler-optimization, intrinsics

I have a program that makes heavy use of the intrinsic command `_BitScanForward` / `_BitScanForward64`  (aka count trailing zeros, TZCNT, CTZ).
I would like to *not* use the intrinsic but instead use the according CPU instruction (available on Haswell and later).

When using gcc or clang (where the intrinsic is called `__builtin_ctz`), I can achieve this by specifying either `-march=haswell` or `-mbmi2` as compiler flags.

The documentation of [_BitScanForward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanforward-bitscanforward64?view=msvc-170) only specifies that the intrinsic is available on all architectures "x86, ARM, x64, ARM64" or "x64, ARM64", but I don't just want it to be available, I want to ensure it is compiled to use the CPU instruction instead of the intrinsic function. I also checked [/Oi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/oi-generate-intrinsic-functions?view=msvc-170) but that doesn't explain it either.

I also searched the web but there are curiously few matches for my question, most just explain how to use intrinsics, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355967/how-to-use-msvc-intrinsics-to-get-the-equivalent-of-this-gcc-code) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206981/intrinsic-for-the-mulx-instruction).

Am I overthinking this and MSVC will create code that magically uses the CPU instruction if the CPU supports it? Are there any flags required? How can I ensure that the CPU instructions are used when available?

**UPDATE**

Here is what it looks like with [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM1ykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJmAOykAA6oCoRODB7evv6BaRmOAqHhUSyx8VxJtpj2xQxCBEzEBDk%2BfgG19VlNLQSlkTFxCckKza3teV3j/YPllaMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmO26iCkqtp9gmGgCCu/uHmCdnyOP4gjd3j2Z7DAOXmOpzcTnGxEwrB%2BD1%2BTyoRywNHC6AgAH0ALJCNxogBq2AASktfgB6ElHBAEAgpBQgMnoVAfAB0LDwyGI6VQVAITLQLBJjAAtF4FCTkCkUiSwgRiGEMh8SaoAGySQWsdAqwXS2UMeUKQW0PDjU4AMQAbnhMAB3U4AETN%2BrMGi4AE44f9nsDXqDtWEmQgYX8dq48FQ4Q8RWFgEdooQ0Va8OgCAg0QQ3rajp8QCAvNKVanTlZYQ8wobwjG4wmkym0ws4gB5KjBKFfYAALTi6QgWZzeckqYrBDREKjSxOiSL9yO06OoaOEFjQ5HRnTdqOGjHJgnvxnu6OkII6wYRxVhZ3M63tvP08X8cTyYHx7XXDPD13Pdzgh2ZgHqnT89vZdox%2BHZsCOb9iR2SddznCA/ztNcN3HaC92nJ9LDXb9XynVCjngnYMwgaUlkAmUo2w3dL2vWcETgt5blAo4uCVVcCPXTdtzfXD0KsNjmIo3D8LcUFnyVATpyorjp1g/CGLAsxJFYjMkK3FDUJ4tcAA5xL3ISRLY7SoOoyScOk2jZJuI4zE0pT2OQ6jdw0tjJB03c9LONcXKMqTxyvHyZPoyydg0WyVM40y9ycjMzFcmd3OEtiYu8iKTMco5BTXCzGJ2F9kt3A8jyOBhsJM35SzCV5byrB9a2GYhG2bJhWw7DkFG7Ah0GzT8CG/AdSJ1YAOLUmiALjIDQqGhyZwK4hjywvKL0SPyIqq%2B8ayK/9cuG2D%2BqjQLGOYib7J8tLrFE2KbzGsiV30hKM34haJKW6idqugb9vkxSELYsLhtOjCDIuwdh2u4CPPBjNDOG1KZ1epdQY%2BqybO%2B5TJpOmcoqOLy/pnXabvBu6sZ0mGzNG%2BH3pAsDgqO1SprQk4AeioG8bBhLCaS6Hnp848MrYlnEZynSZuPYrktKksGDLSrKzWgc63qqgABViCYOgoxarsPz7Pq3tHY6IrhkGKYIxC0Yi/LMEPWaT2x4yuYi7rerTfDlJ0x2fzTABPf8NDd6VmMff8lR2HTvbXdrOt7L8PZI3WjB02DvbAMBTf13CNrXHnwI5um8P/T3iaWo46iUNPBP/COuulJ2lgXOOwbk7PIM55bdzDtj4qYsTHpGiAk5Tn6zfTp82Kzh6cenF2jgLnuSen/9O6hl7aP71PafR%2BnM/So4l43vO1xnlvqPbjNO9t/yV6OZO1/C4f/yz8/zbi/PC9bmcT/3gmrITy/r8Hsv1L323jnPeU9D52zftOYWG1BTzjordJim5QJBS4M3OE9t3R7AREiCqqI0RogOIYYA%2BCOLCUSG4REmBkSYDwWiAA4hEOQOI0TEgeGSI4QhMCvEpNSWkZJGC8glJCKgcRGCbF5KgfkVoxQShJAYIwXgmDAEwCSAgnsUiYAUGVSWFVgbVXWvLBqLZ1adgUPQtwOILByAAJLBEVtYiIlco4EHzGmFmQ9pqW0KvzFG643gmhtnII4IAjj4OiLmWgjgGAENoAAL1oLQOu5NRwlQwRLKWejZa1QqA2JsxijAazMXQixaIrG2PsY4rW0cdbJKMB4qBXjrY%2BJNj9fx2cgkhLCREqJMTYlJKNiksWaT7jlXLKtascs6qNmVqrMs7ZTHmMsTYuxDinHdVccDIC9T9yNOPM0q8rTTSBOCaEtE4S6A9IcPExJ7jUnLW0Rk8ZNUjiGKVirNWBSFnFKWeU1ZVSeoe02aDbZ0D9mITad%2BDppzzmRLCAQggfTblDPubCf4dQ5w4JROiLEOJ8RElJOSHhNI6QkgZMyVk7JOTcgkfyIUIoZGSl9LqNkoplSqnVJqJleoDRGgIKaC01o7QOkFE6V0DzdFPIMVMvJTUTGtUxEIXEPyVmVI6lXQQGz3EAKOGSLwzLgAoiOLQAQ0Z6CyqMGiWJnYfY6TJNA0phARCGAJJgM0cQlAqggOYJUZrWyWs7KQIFA0kEBODtvX1UZ/UchOSqOQQtdmnLicgDVkh%2BlbLueGEZOixkywmdkyoRjzXzPlViJVpTlkVLWdXQFWr14RV1fqw1xqVwRotVa6NiFbUkntRYR1ogGAurdcQJQXqzA%2BvycQ9tqBA21p2AEnK4aJ1RtQCcyF8arbHnwUmwQabgUZuLFmx5ubnmvJmR84t6QFVlrKSqqtKaakDLqdqvVGQDU0KNSao4MpZmRqnTanuPa%2B2GBNCQK0LQNSpu9d%2B89y6Z31xDV%2B95czl0xskHG5FmbRnSyHPoyZOSFZnrmYUq9yrK3/KdkGvWdbdwvrwG%2B9AH6VzQeQ3%2BztAGE0OuEP2kDxAwPEFRFBpDv6A2UafUc5jwno0hLXRh1FwYGD4DDAezBGKqG4PRDEohJDxxkIoZimhGmGFMJIZg/TRwPB6oGBOwpSSFBjleY1ZqXySk3srYuOzpm1Plgs4IQjcquzufs9Kvznz5XfPLb8xxgXMHouwV5gzCrcWElYUGMzPmrNFps4Fl50rHP%2BbMaW0jqzotybS2sXzQnQsBcIHZnL%2BHpmVYvQVxVRWos1ZS7sEumBPPUPM%2BVjLTnWq2aC/VmVg3qsEA86V%2BLfXLMhaa8NurBa3k/qq21ErQYQxKceAe6URwWCqwYBAbZkqBxhB0j2ZAYREbnZ7kwLwRAdkKC8JE/86X5s2bCGgny0DITPciXcjgKxaCcAAKy8D8BwLQpBUCcGEhhSwmY1gbG9P8HgpACCaCBysAA1iAHYOwmQE%2BJyT0n%2BhOCSAh1jmHnBeC0g0BjrHKw4CwBgIgFAkiUh0DiOQSgfIuf0HiMAaoZhSBYAtJsXElorT1g0ZD9HNBInusoNEansZmDEE9pwdHfI2CCHrJLLXUPeBYAO0YcQxuxd4EhA4PAbraSW8wKoTAyAHtbHR9KOo1PDTRBVprjwWBqdkRYNroHfADDAAUFL60svGCh5kIIJ14gpAJ/kEoNQ1PdCBHkcYM6lh9B4GiLSSAKxUApAaA7wUFRWRmHSgdjYAYCIICYAoK0dRaDpXrDsOndQXcNBcApqYfhAghAqvLPQhRMgCCHxP9IU%2BGDzDqnoOwffegTDaJ4Doy/e%2B24EH0Voi/8PL/XzPwIswD9j6X6g1Y6xNgSGB2DqnlvYccDwppJUgoVRHGAMgZATEzBMi14QC4CEAkAMw5RLC8CY7G5LC4746E6k6IHE7k4cCU6kAh6g4M6Q7Q4v504gAM7QFaDM5s4QBID87c5kAUAQDkGC4gDC5mCi7i5siYDR4y5y7x6K4EDK4Lhq5hAtBG466SJ64EAG60BG7Q6m5EIW4SHW6r727U5O4u5u7x6e4g6W4%2B5%2B6ewB5bDQ7B6h4rBUAR5R7S6x7y68D8CJ6iDJ7SAWFp4qDqCW66A7D6BEIoB542A%2B7F7HYw7l5ZCV5d4949DOAQCuCn5BAKaH6LAFBz4NBhGT4NCREjBn474ND74b65DD7dCr577r6JFVC2An6b55Bn65GX5H7X4KDI537X5qHg6kDYG8Av5v4f5f4/5/7VCAHzggFEDEDgGoJQFM4rAIAtgjDeFqFoEYFYHU64G2D4GM4wFwEE5E5IGIEoHd71HTG07zFEGkAs7s40E85UEHHxBmjigpBohmiuhogE5ohspi6urMGsGmEcEXLcGq6W7q78Hx666MAiGG7U6SHm46Em6yG27yGO7O6u5cEqGCBe7qGF6aHaFB6ygh7cBh6GFKLGEx7sFomp5J7sAp62GKD2GZ7%2BAuFGBuEI4eGF5eGl6%2BECB8L1ii4r675%2BAhGD5FGZGj5lBX6pAxFZBxH8klBlFRFZGslpFhEsmpGlE8nlEFH9CSkylDDlErCVG34EkP4cB1ENE06v5sr7YKCnFHCXEujLFdH4A9F9GQHbHY6kDDFNSjGLEIErFk7jG8Ah5cAaBTHP5bH042mwEoFmBP44FbGEG2lDoZDOCSBAA).
Please be nice, my assembly reading skills are pretty basic.

GCC uses `tzcnt` with haswell/bmi2, otherwise resorts to `rep bsf`.
MSVC uses `bsf` without `rep`.

I also found [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683690/confusion-about-bsr-and-lzcnt#43443701), which states that:

- "Using a redundant rep prefix for bsr was generally defined to be ignored [...]". I wonder whether the same is true for `bsf`?
- It explains (as I knew) that `bsf` is not the same as `tzcnt`, however MSVC doesn't appear to check for input == 0

This adds the questions: Why does `bsf` work for MSVC?

**UPDATE**

Okay, this was easy, I actually call `_BitScanForward` for MSVC. Doh!

**UPDATE**

So I added a bit of unnecessary confusion here. Ideally I would like to use an intrinsic `__tzcnt`, but that doesn't exist in MSVC so I resorted to `_BitScanForward` plus an extra check to account for `0` input.

However, MSVC supports LZCNT, where I have a similar issue (but it is used less in my code).

Slightly updated question would be: How does MSVC deal with LZCNT (instead of TZCNT)?

**Answer:** see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/lzcnt16-lzcnt-lzcnt64?view=msvc-170). Specifically: "On Intel processors that don't support the `lzcnt` instruction, the instruction byte encoding is executed as `bsr` (bit scan reverse). If code portability is a concern, consider use of the `_BitScanReverse` intrinsic instead."

The article suggests to resort to `bsr` if older CPUs are a concern. To me, this implies that there is no compiler flag to control this, instead they suggest to manually identify the `__cpu` and then call either `bsr` or `lzcnt`.

In short, MSVC has no support for different CPU architectures (beyond x86/64/ARM).

Comment: What does the assembly (or disassembly) look like of the routine that is using the intrinsic?

Comment: You probably mean [__lzcnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/lzcnt16-lzcnt-lzcnt64?view=msvc-170) intrinsic - it always generates `lzcnt` instruction and will be just incorrectly decoded on older cpu, the article also explains how to correctly check if the cpu supports it. _BitScanForward  just generates `bsf` instruction which is available since intel 386

Comment: @dewaffled Actually I mean the something like `__tzcnt`, but that doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: `bsf` and `bsr` are hardware instructions since 386.  `tzcnt` and `lzcnt` are faster on AMD, and give well-defined results for input=0.  But not enough faster to be worth branching every time, only like once outside a loop.  GCC and clang typically use `tzcnt` for `__builtin_ctz` even if it's not guaranteed to run as `tzcnt` instead of `bsf`, since it gives the same results for non-zero inputs, and they don't support taking advantage of the AMD-defined semantics of BSF leaving the destination reg unmodified on input = 0.  (Intel CPUs do it too, but don't document it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to target specifically *Haswell*, but there's a way to assume AVX2 availability (`/arch:AVX2`), which also assumes `tzcnt` availability and other BMI1 and BMI2 instructions, along with FMA3. And there's a way to tune for a wide set of architectures (`/favor` option; unfortunately only three wide groups available: common Intel, common AMD, Intel Atom).

**There's no reason why `_BitScanReverse` wouldn't generate `tzcnt` under `/arch:AVX2`, except missed optimization opportunity.** For example `_mm_set1_*` intrinsics do generate different code under different `/arch` options. Even the intrinsics explicit named are not always used to generate the instruction they imply. Like `_mm_load_si128` may be no-op (fused with a subsequent op using memory operand instead of a register). Or `_mm_extract_pi16` with zero argument may be just `movd`.

I've created [Developer Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missed-optimization-_BitScanForward-and-/10444723) about this missed optimization. For now, you can use `<bit>` functions, which do runtime detection by default, but use `lzcnt` / `tzcnt` unconditionally with `/arch:AVX2`.

(There's virtually no way to avoid using AVX2 and BMI instructions with `/arch:AVX2` in an optimized build, as there's always some room for auto-vectorization, so `_BitScanReverse` cannot be "portable to legacy processors" with `/arch:AVX2` and above anyway)

Comment: In a recent question you used `-mavx2` with GCC/Clang.  The equivalent of MSVC's `/arch:AVX2` in modern GCC/Clang is `-march=x86-64-v3` which enables AVX2+FMA+BMI1+BMI2, i.e. a Haswell baseline.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels

Comment: Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/E5babPseT - MSVC `-arch:AVX2` or `-arch:AVX512` uses `sarx` for `a >> c`, but legacy `ror` instead of `rorx` for `std::rotr(x, 2)`, so that's a missed optimization.  With `-arch:AVX` or lower, it doesn't use `sarx`, just classic `sar` after moving the count to `cl`.

Answer (score 2):

[not exactly answering the question in title, rather trying to solve OP's problem]

If you can afford a reasonably-recent compiler and can specify /std:c++20) - you can use standard C++ std::countl_zero / std::countl_one / std::countr_zero / std::countr_one ; for details, refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit .

From personal experience: these happen to work like a charm over 3 different platforms and 3 different compilers.

Comment: But do you know a way to tell MSVC to compile `std::countl_zero` to `lzcnt` instead of checking for non-zero and then `bsr` / `xor reg, 31` (or subtract from 31 if it doesn't know that trick)?   According to https://godbolt.org/z/YTaxdKofz, it seems MSVC will do that with `-arch:AVX2` (in practice there are no CPUs with AVX2 but not BMI1, I'm pretty sure).  MSVC doesn't understand ` -arch:x86-64-v3` and makes code that checks an ISA-version global at run-time, which might be not bad since the `bsr` code path also has to branch on the input being non-zero.

Comment: usually in these situations, I edit the title to represent the question better, and then look for an actual canonical Q&A for the question I set out to answer, or if it doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: @PeterCordes are you 100% sure it will work faster on those platforms where compiler doesn't do it? If so - there is always an option to open a ticket against MSVC team. In general, personally I am trying to trust the compiler writers (as a big fat rule of thumb, they tend to know much better about the CPUs than mere mortals do - and BTW, having different sequences being optimal on different architectures is extremely common).

Comment: Where compiler doesn't do what?  I'm sure `lzcnt` is faster than `bsr`/`xor` on all existing x86 CPUs, and AFAIK the only way to get MSVC to emit it for `countl_zero` is to compile with `-arch:AVX2`.  There might be other ways; I don't know MSVC as well as others.  A lot faster on AMD (see https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/).  And if the compiler can't prove the input is non-zero, it needs even more extra instructions than that.  On Intel CPUs, `lzcnt` performs about the same as `bsr`, but on Skylake and later without a false dependency.  (For `bsr` it's a true dependency).

Comment: I've filed several missed-optimization bugs over the years with GCC and clang, and have been asked for advice on what's fast a couple times by clang developers. In terms of knowing what's fast in asm, I and a few other CPU-architecture experts that post here on Stack Overflow (e.g. BeeOnRope, Andreas Abel, harold, and some others) are at or beyond the knowledge level of the average compiler developer, for the ISAs we know about.

Comment: And even though some compiler devs know architectures pretty well, compilers themselves often don't make optimal code.  e.g. see [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) and [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) for analysis of why compiler-generated code is sub-optimal in those cases, and what would be faster.  I might be just some random guy on the Internet, but there's my evidence I know what I'm talking about, since you asked.

Comment: @PeterCordes Great, thanks a lot - and make sure to keep posting missing-optimization bugs to compilers (just include MSVC to the mix, the best person to contact there is 
IIRC Eric Brumer); that's THE way of handling it, not writing unmaintainable unportable ad-hoc abominations of code at app-level.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted above, MSVC doesn't appear to have support for different CPU architectures (beyond x86/64/ARM).

[This article says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/lzcnt16-lzcnt-lzcnt64?view=msvc-170): "On Intel processors that don't support the `lzcnt` instruction, the instruction byte encoding is executed as `bsr` (bit scan reverse). If code portability is a concern, consider use of the `_BitScanReverse` intrinsic instead."

The article suggests to resort to `bsr` if older CPUs are a concern. To me, this implies that there is no compiler flag to control this, instead they suggest to manually identify the `__cpuid` and then call either `bsr` or `lzcnt` depending on the result.

**UPDATE**

As @dewaffled pointed out, there are indeed `_tzcnt_u32` / `_tzcnt_u64` in the [x64 intrinsics list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list?view=msvc-170).

I got mislead by looking at the [Alphabetical listing of intrinsic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/lzcnt16-lzcnt-lzcnt64?view=msvc-170) on the left side of the pane. I wonder whether there is a distinction between "intrinsics" and "intrinsic functions", i.e. `_tzcnt_u64` is an intrinsic but not an intrinsic function.

Comment: There are `_tzcnt_u32`/ `_tzcnt_u64` if you need those.

Comment: `_tzcnt_u64` will compile to a single instruction, never a function call.  IDK what Intel means by "intrinsic function"; perhaps some SVML library functions like `_mm_sin_ps` where there's no hardware instruction, it's only provided in Intel's math library.

Comment: But the same is true for __lzcnt, I understand it will never compile to a function, still it is listed in the alphabetical list of intrinsic _functions_. I am also not sure whether "function" really means complex code for whether a CPU instruction is also a minimal "function"...